# After position: fixed, another container takes 100% of browser instead of an available space

Tags: html, css

I want to create a left navigation bar with the position: fixed attribute so that it stands in place as we scroll down.

I have `.fullPage` div with `display: flex` to show these divs horizontally.

When I add `position: fixed` attribute to the `left-navbar`, second div `container-fluid-center` takes 100% of browser's width instead of 100% of available space.

```
<div class="fullPage">
    <div class="left-navbar">
                
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid-center">
                
    </div>
</div>

.fullPage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.fullPage .left-navbar {
  width: 88px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  position: fixed;
}
.fullPage .container-fluid-center {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: You can give to `.container-fluid-center` a `margin-left: 88px;`

Answer (score 2):

As per [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), with position set to `fixed` "*The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout.*".

In order to fix your issue, you can give to `.container-fluid-center` a `margin-left: 88px;`, so that it will not "overlap" with `.left-navbar`

Answer (score 1):

When you give `position:fixed` to the `.left-navbar`

A `position:fixed` element does not leave a gap in the page where it would normally have been located.

So You need to `.fullPage .container-fluid-center` give width like this

```
.fullPage .container-fluid-center {
  width: calc(100% - 88px);
  height: 100vh;
}
```

So it is worked as you need

Comment: In this way `.container-fluid-center` width will be reduced but the element will still rendered starting from the left margin of the page, therefore it will still overlap with `.left-navbar`

Comment: Here you can see what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/5p2tL7y6/